# How to print p-values with exponent (scientific) notation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scientific-notation

When printing values in R using 'ggplot', I'm facing issues to write the exponent proprerly. See the plot below, and an example of what I would like to obtain hand-written in red.

```
data <- data.frame(var = 1:10,
                  pvalue=c(0.1,0.001,0.0000133233,0.2,0.2222,0.43254,0.1,0.67,0.6777,0.2)) %>% 
  mutate(pvalue=as.character(signif(pvalue,digits=2)))# %>%mutate(pvalue = sub("e","10^",pvalue) )


data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = var)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, label = pvalue), parse=T)
```

[image: Ggplot]

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [plotmath](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) which explains the formatting rules for mathematical expressions in plots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert scientific notation +e to 10^(y) with superscripts in geom\_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61749815/convert-scientific-notation-e-to-10y-with-superscripts-in-geom-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to change the values with `e` to exponent forms, you only need to add `%.%`  to your commented code.

```
data <- data.frame(var = 1:10,
                   pvalue = c(0.1,0.001,0.0000133233,0.2,0.2222,
                              0.43254,0.1,0.67,0.6777,0.2)) %>% 
                   mutate(pvalue = as.character(signif(pvalue,digits=2))) %>%
                   mutate(pvalue = sub("e","%.% 10^",pvalue) )
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = var)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, label = pvalue), parse = TRUE)
```

The result:

[image]